# Generic MASM code: storing 8 or 16 bits of a register depending on TYPE of a symbol

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to write an array-reversing function that works correctly whether the static array holds `BYTE`s or `WORD`s.

This is what I have so far where I assumed the array was of size `WORD`

```
.data
    myArray WORD 1231h, 2342h, 3353h, 4564h, 5675h, 7, 9

.code
main proc
    mov eax, 0  ;index of the left side of the array
    mov esi, SIZEOF myArray
    sub esi, TYPE myArray   ;index of the right side of the array

    Switch:
        movsx edx, [myArray + eax]  ;puts the left element of the array in eax

        xchg dx,  [myArray + esi]   ;exchange edx with the right element of the array

        mov [myArray + eax], dx ;puts the right element into the left part of the array

        add eax, TYPE myArray   ;eax is currently pointing to leftPtr so we add the appropriate amount to 
                                ;it depending on the size of each element in myArray. This way it will point
                                ;to the next element in the array

        sub esi, TYPE myArray   ;same concept as above except we are subtracting the amount from the right pointer
        cmp esi, eax            ;compare the right pointer to the left pointer
        jnle Switch             ;Jump if the right pointer is !(<=) the left pointer

main endp
end main
```

I can use the `movzx/movsx` instruction to move the smaller sized value from the array into a 32-bit register.

**The problem is writing something that assembles to an 8bit store or 16bit store depending on `TYPE`.**

Comment: Don't use `xchg` with a memory operand unless you *want* the effect of the implicit `lock` prefix (an atomic read-modify-write memory access, and a full memory barrier).  It's *much* slower than just using two tmp registers.  Also don't forget to `ret` at the end of your function, unless MASM adds one for you.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the main question here, though.  You may have to use MASM macros to select between `mov [mem], dl` and `mov [mem], dx`.  Selecting on `TYPE` of the array only works when it's static anyway (rather than a function arg), right?  AFAIK, you can't tell MASM you want `[esi]` to imply a specific operand-size.  But I don't use MASM, just NASM/YASM and GNU as.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a symbol conditionally on the type of myArray to be either the text `dl`, `dx` or `edx` and use that in place of the register. Something like:

```
    IF TYPE myArray EQ TYPE BYTE
@DX TEXTEQU <dl>
    ELSEIF TYPE myArray EQ TYPE WORD
@DX TEXTEQU <dx>
    ELSEIF TYPE myArray EQ TYPE DWORD
@DX TEXTEQU <edx>
    ENDIF

    mov @DX, [myArray + eax]   ;puts the left element of the array in DX
    xchg @DX, [myArray + esi]  ;exchange DX with the right element of the array
    mov [myArray + eax], @DX   ;puts the right element into the left part of the array
```