# Is there a general <type> ptr directive in assembly that can infer the type from the label?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Is there a general  ptr directive in assembly that can infer the type from the label?

For example, we have a variable of some type, it can be byte, word or dword, and I want to move it to one of the registers, is there a way to do it if we don't know its type?

```
.data
VAR1 dword 2
VAR2 byte 3
.code
mov eax, ? ptr VAR1
mov eax, ? ptr VAR2
```

Comment: Not really, you might have been able to use `movsx`, but if VAR1 or VAR2 were the same size as the register _EAX_ (which is 32 bits) it would have complained. There is a recent answer by @RossRidge that might suggest a way to do such a thing by using MASM's ability to do conditional assembly. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37776062/3857942

Comment: The type is automatically inferred from the type of the label. You only need to use PTR when you want to access the memory using a different size. So you can just do `mov eax, VAR1`. On the other hand, `mov eax, BYTE PTR VAR2` is illegal, and so is `mov eax, VAR2` for the same reason. The size of the of both operands of the MOV instruction need to be same. As Michael Petch suggests, you need to use MOVSX or MOVZX (sign-extending or zero-extending the value) for the second statement.

Comment: @Ross: This might be why AMD gave [`movsxd` a different mnemonic from the other forms of `movsx`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) when they designed AMD64, to make sure `movsx eax, var` wasn't legal when `var` was 32bit.  The opcode is intended for use only with a REX prefix (to sign-extend to 64b), and maybe they wanted to really discourage using it as a synonym for `mov r32, r/m32`.  (IDK how it decodes on K8; maybe it still decodes to using an ALU port as well as a load port like `movsxd r64, m32` does, according to Agner Fog's table)